# Dynamic invocation of methods in DLLs; How to change method signature?

Tags: vb.net, dll, delegates

I am using some interesting code to perform dynamic unmanaged dll calling:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Module NativeMethods
Declare Function LoadLibrary Lib "kernel32" Alias "LoadLibraryA" (ByVal dllToLoad As String) As IntPtr
Declare Function GetProcAddress Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hModule As IntPtr, ByVal procedureName As String) As IntPtr
Declare Function FreeLibrary Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hModule As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Module

Module Program
<UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)> _
Delegate Function MultiplyByTen(ByVal numberToMultiply As Integer) As Integer


Sub Main()
    Dim pDll As IntPtr = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary("MultiplyByTen.dll")

    Dim pAddressOfFunctionToCall As IntPtr = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(pDll, "MultiplyByTen")

    Dim multiplyByTen As MultiplyByTen = DirectCast(Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pAddressOfFunctionToCall, GetType(MultiplyByTen)), MultiplyByTen)

    Dim theResult As Integer = multiplyByTen(10)

    Console.WriteLine(theResult)

    NativeMethods.FreeLibrary(pAddressOfFunctionToCall)
End Sub

End Module
```

I want to be able to change the parameter signature and type of the delegate to void or to a function returning integer, string, or boolean.

Basically, I want my program (interpreter) to be able to call upon any method in any unmanaged dll that the programmer has access to... since I cannot predict what method the programmer will want to have access to - I'd like to enable them to have access to any useful method.

This seems like it's possible in vb.net - perhaps with reflection? - but I'm just not sure how to do it.

--- EDIT: Here's what I've come up with:

```
<UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)> _
Delegate Function DelegateInteger(<[ParamArray]()> ByVal args() As Object) As Integer

...

    Dim GetStdHandle = NativeDllCallIntegerMethod("kernel32", "GetStdHandle", -11)
...
    Function NativeDllCallIntegerMethod(ByVal DllPath As String, ByVal DllMethod As String, ByVal ParamArray Arguments() As Object) As Integer
    Dim pDll As IntPtr = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(DllPath)

    Dim pAddressOfFunctionToCall As IntPtr = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(pDll, DllMethod)

    Dim IntegerFunction As DelegateInteger = DirectCast(Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pAddressOfFunctionToCall, GetType(DelegateInteger)), DelegateInteger)

    Dim theResult As Object = IntegerFunction.DynamicInvoke(Arguments)

    NativeDllCallIntegerMethod = theResult

    NativeMethods.FreeLibrary(pAddressOfFunctionToCall)
    End Function
```

This raises a complaint on the line with 'Dim theResult = ...' on it. The error is "Object of type 'System.Int32' cannot be converted to type 'System.Object[]'."

I seem to be getting *somewhere* but... where? I don't really know.

Comment: So to be clear, you want the user to be able to specify a method name and signature and have your program automatically generate the proper code to call the function?

Comment: Yes. That's what I'm looking to do.

Comment: This is not going to be easy for the most general case (where any signature can be used). You will need to learn how IL works to emit the equivalent of ".NET assembly code" to generate a dynamic method invoker. However, this project may be a good starting point: http://dynamic.codeplex.com/

Comment: I think I mentioned TypeBuilder.DefinePInvokeMethod() before.

Comment: @HansPassant: I found [this article on DefinePInvokeMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa330122%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and I've got the code for vb.net - is this what you were thinking of?

Comment: Found a better article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hb2et051%28v=VS.110%29.aspx)

Comment: It is old but someone may use the code. There is an error in *NativeMethods.FreeLibrary(pAddressOfFunctionToCall)*. It should be *NativeMethods.FreeLibrary(pDll )*.

Answer (score 1):

I've got it. I can now dynamically call methods:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Reflection.Emit
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Module DynamicInvocation

Sub Main()
    Dim DI As New DynamicInvoke
    DI.Invoke("FreeConsole", "Kernel32", GetType(Boolean), Nothing)
    DI.Invoke("AllocConsole", "Kernel32", GetType(Boolean), Nothing)
    Dim StandardOutputHandle = DI.Invoke("GetStdHandle", "Kernel32", GetType(Integer), -11)

    DI.Invoke("WriteConsoleA", "Kernel32", GetType(Integer), StandardOutputHandle, "Testing!", 8, 0, 0)

End Sub

End Module

Public Class DynamicInvoke
',  Optional ByVal AssemblyName As String = "DynamicInvoke", Optional ByVal TypeName As String = "DynamicType", Optional ByVal Convention As CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, Optional ByVal CharacterSet As CharSet = CharSet.Ansi

Public AssemblyName As String = "DynamicInvoke"
Public TypeName As String = "DynamicType"
Public Convention As CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi
Public CharacterSet As CharSet = CharSet.Ansi

Function Invoke(ByVal MethodName As String, ByVal LibraryName As String, ByVal ReturnType As Type, ByVal ParamArray Parameters() As Object)

    Dim ParameterTypesArray As Array

    If Parameters IsNot Nothing Then
        ParameterTypesArray = Array.CreateInstance(GetType(Type), Parameters.Length)
        Dim PTIndex As Integer = 0

        For Each Item In Parameters
            If Item IsNot Nothing Then
                ParameterTypesArray(PTIndex) = Item.GetType
            Else
                'ParameterTypesArray(PTIndex) = 0
            End If
            PTIndex += 1
        Next
    Else
        ParameterTypesArray = Nothing
    End If

    Dim ParameterTypes() As Type = ParameterTypesArray


    Dim asmName As New AssemblyName(AssemblyName)
    Dim dynamicAsm As AssemblyBuilder = _
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(asmName, _
            AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave)

    ' Create the module.
    Dim dynamicMod As ModuleBuilder = _
        dynamicAsm.DefineDynamicModule(asmName.Name, asmName.Name & ".dll")

    ' Create the TypeBuilder for the class that will contain the 
    ' signature for the PInvoke call.
    Dim tb As TypeBuilder = dynamicMod.DefineType(TypeName, _
        TypeAttributes.Public Or TypeAttributes.UnicodeClass)

    Dim mb As MethodBuilder = tb.DefinePInvokeMethod( _
        MethodName, _
        LibraryName, _
        MethodAttributes.Public Or MethodAttributes.Static Or MethodAttributes.PinvokeImpl, _
        CallingConventions.Standard, _
        ReturnType, _
        ParameterTypes, _
        Convention, _
        CharacterSet)

    ' Add PreserveSig to the method implementation flags. NOTE: If this line
    ' is commented out, the return value will be zero when the method is
    ' invoked.
    mb.SetImplementationFlags( _
        mb.GetMethodImplementationFlags() Or MethodImplAttributes.PreserveSig)

    ' The PInvoke method does not have a method body.

    ' Create the class and test the method.
    Dim t As Type = tb.CreateType()

    Dim mi As MethodInfo = t.GetMethod(MethodName)
    Return mi.Invoke(Me, Parameters)

    '' Produce the .dll file.
    'Console.WriteLine("Saving: " & asmName.Name & ".dll")
    'dynamicAsm.Save(asmName.Name & ".dll")
End Function

End Class
```