# Declaring third party DLL dynamically in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, dll, import

I'm facing a problem importing a DLL on different environments.
I have to check Windows platform and import the third-party DLL that will be placed in `C:\Program Files\` (for `32-bit`) or `C:Program Files (x86)\` (for `64-bit`).

Before the code was written like this:

```
Declare Function RDRCConnect Lib "c:\program files\TP-DLL\RDRCAP32.DLL" (ByVal lpszServerName As String, ByVal lNetConnType As Integer, ByVal lpszParam1 As String, ByVal lpszParam2 As String, ByVal lpszParam3 As String, ByRef lNetConn As Integer, ByRef lNetErr As Integer) As Integer  
Declare Function RDRCDisconnect Lib "c:\program files\TP-DLL\RDRCAP32.DLL" (ByVal lNetConn As Integer, ByRef lNetErr As Integer) As Integer
```

...and I changed to use attributes:

```
Private Const CheminDLL As String = "C:\Program Files\TP-DLL\RDRCAP32.DLL"

<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport(CheminDLL)>
Private Shared Function RDRCConnect(ByVal lpszServerName As String, ByVal lNetConnType As Integer, ByVal lpszParam1 As String, ByVal lpszParam2 As String, ByVal lpszParam3 As String, ByRef lNetConn As Integer, ByRef lNetErr As Integer) As Integer
End Function
```

How can I change the DLL path dinamically in this scenario, once the DLLImport expects a Constant as parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to pass anything other than a constant into the attribute, since attributes, by definition are evaluated at compile-time, not at runtime.  There may be better alternatives, but one option I can give you would be to create separate imports for each version:

```
<DllImport("C:\Program Files\TP-DLL\RDRCAP32.DLL", EntryPoint := "RDRCConnect")>
Private Shared Function RDRCConnect32(ByVal lpszServerName As String, ByVal lNetConnType As Integer, ByVal lpszParam1 As String, ByVal lpszParam2 As String, ByVal lpszParam3 As String, ByRef lNetConn As Integer, ByRef lNetErr As Integer) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("C:\Program Files (x86)\TP-DLL\RDRCAP32.DLL", EntryPoint := "RDRCConnect")>
Private Shared Function RDRCConnect64(ByVal lpszServerName As String, ByVal lNetConnType As Integer, ByVal lpszParam1 As String, ByVal lpszParam2 As String, ByVal lpszParam3 As String, ByRef lNetConn As Integer, ByRef lNetErr As Integer) As Integer
End Function
```

Then you would need to choose which one to call appropriately each time you call the method.

Comment: Thanks Steven! I just changed the EntryPoint operator to := instead = :)

Comment: Oops!  I fixed it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon this a couple of days ago when I had a similar issue to yours and it put me on the right path. Look for it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641321/dynamic-invocation-of-methods-in-dlls-how-to-change-method-signature).

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks for your reply! I will try both suggestions from you and tcarvin later. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If the dlls are the same (same name and signatures) but just in different locations then you can p/invoke [LoadLibrary](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.loadlibrary) explicitly with the full path of the dll as determined at runtime.  As long as you do this **before** you invoke any of the exported APIs then it will use the one already loaded as long as the name of the dll in the import is the same.

Comment: Thanks for your help tcarvin! Yes the DLLs are the same, they are just in different locations. I will try to implement this later.